# Ngrx Problem - Unable to Understand What the Problem Is

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

My compiler is complaining about the following ngrx code after I switch to the later version of nodejs and updated a few dependencies in package.json.

I'm using Angular 13 and ngrx version 13 and NodeJS 16.

Any javascript guru out there please help.

```
@Effect()
loadMyWorkitemList$ = this.dataPersistence.fetch(WorkflowActionTypes.LoadMyWorkitemList, {
  run: (action: LoadMyWorkitemList, state: WorkflowPartialState) => {
    return this.workitemsService.mylist().pipe(
      map(result => {
        return new fromWorkflowActions.MyWorkitemListLoaded(result.payload);
      })
    );
  },

  onError: (action: LoadMyWorkitemList, error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    return new fromWorkflowActions.MyWorkitemListLoadError(error);
  }
});
```

The error is:

```
Type '(action: LoadMyWorkitemList, state: WorkflowPartialState) => Observable<MyWorkitemListLoaded>' is not assignable to type '(a: LoadMyWorkitemList, slices_0: WorkflowPartialState) => void | Action | Observable<Action>'.
  Type 'Observable<MyWorkitemListLoaded>' is not assignable to type 'void | Action | Observable<Action>'.
    Type 'Observable<MyWorkitemListLoaded>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Action>': _isScalar, _trySubscribe, _subscribets(2322)
data-persistence.d.ts(26, 5): The expected type comes from property 'run' which is declared here on type 'FetchOpts<[WorkflowPartialState], LoadMyWorkitemList>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using an old `ngrx` syntax, since you are using version 13, `effects` uses `createEffect`, along with `ofType` based on the official [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#writing-effects):

```js
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import * as UserActions from '../store/user/actions/user.actions.ts';
...

@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {

  getUsers$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(UserActions.getUsers)
     mergeMap(() => this.userService.getUsers().pipe(
       map((response) => of(UserActions.getUsersSuccess({ users: response.users }))),
       catchError(() => UserActions.getUsersFail())
     ))
  ));

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private userService: Service) {}
}
```